# "in an era of” vs. “in an era with"

Tags: prepositions

> A) We are living in an era **of** untold opportunities
>   B) We are living in an era **with** untold opportunities

Which one sounds more natural?

Comment: *On average* we probably use ***of*** more often than ***with*** for such constructions, but the more popular choice varies according to the *exact* context. It's usually *He is a man **of** means* and *He is a man **with** a mission,* and you'd rarely if ever encounter *those* two prepositions the other way around. But no such extreme preference applies to your example - it's just that ***of*** is *somewhat* more common, not that either is "correct" or "incorrect".

Answer (score 1):

“*of opportunity*”” is the more “idiomatic” expression,  but both usages are grammatical.

America, for instance, is  known as the [Land of opportunity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land%20of%20opportunity)